# Adobe Illustrator shape edges not lining up, shape builder creating weird shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

So I have only had this problem since updating to CC19. I'm not sure the best way to explain it but when I zoom in 100% the shape edge guide does not accurately line up with the shape fill (or stroke).

When I go to use the shape builder tool, it changes the shape, sometimes adding wonky lines.

I have tried GPU and CPU previews and that doesn't make a difference.

Here is an example of shape builder:
[image: Example of weird issue]

Here is an example of the shape edge not matching the shape. 
[image: Weird issue #2]

Comment: [Align to pixel grid](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/pixel-perfect.html)

Comment: nope, that's not it

Comment: There is absolutely no other cause I am aware of.